# Does docker container maintain volume data?

Tags: docker

This might come across as a stupid question, but I am unable to figure something about docker volumes. Going through the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) I can see that we can map the host machine file system on the container for persistent storage. Following the instruction I was successfully able to mount a folder on my container.

Once I exec bash into the container, I can see the mapped directory structure there as expected. My question is, how is the data mapped between these two paths, that is from the container to the mount volume on host OS. Is the data duplicated or the container directly stores the data on the volume on host OS and the mapped paths are shown for something like symlink ?

This question comes across since we are trying to maintain a large amount of data on a mounted disk but accessible by the container, with the assumption that mounting volume would directly store the data on the disk and nothing on the container.

Comment: "Is the data duplicated or the container directly stores the data on the volume on host OS ...?" - the latter. No symlinks, just mount points. Think like mounting a USB stick to a PC, you choose where to mount it and once it's mounted data is written directly to the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Docker documentation refers to this type of mount as a "bind mount"; that's also a technical Linux term that allows one part of the filesystem to also appear somewhere else, and there's a `mount --bind` option you can use outside of Docker (usually a pretty specialized option).

On native Linux, the host content and the container-visible content are literally the exact same disk content.  If you have a bind-mounted host directory or a named Docker volume mounted over a container directory, all reads and writes will use that mounted content, and in fact nothing will be written to the container filesystem on that path.

---

You mention symlinks; these are always resolved as filenames in their respective filesystem space.  If the mounted filesystem has a symlink `passwd -> /etc/passwd` then reading it will yield the host's password file on the host, and the container's password file inside the container.  If it has a symlink `f -> ../f` then it will look at the directory above the mount point in whichever the local filesystem is.

On non-Linux this process is a little bit more technically complex since there is typically a Linux virtual machine involved in the mix.  This usually manifests as file synchronization appearing slow.  For data you don't need to directly access as a human, storing it in a named Docker volume will usually be faster.

Comment: Understood. One more thing, from the doc I can see that docker managed volumes are stored under /var/lib/docker/volumes/volumename/_data. Since /var will be on host OS, is there a way we could have docker managed volumes point to externally mounted disks on the OS. Or we should resort to using mount --bind based file system access.

Comment: @arjunkhera you can mount an external disk to `/var/lib/docker/volumes` or configure the `docker` daemon's [`--data-root`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) to whatever.

Comment: Got it. Thanks @masseyb